# What's the right way to minify & obfuscate JS from maven?

Tags: javascript, java, maven

I've got java webapp that's built with maven. It has lots of JS files and I have to build a bundle - a single file, minificated & obfuscated in perfect.

Now I use [minify-maven-plugin](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin) that's used YUI or Closure compressors.

But both these compressors fail when I write in JS smth like this:

```
$http.get("/url").then().catch().finally()
```

So I have to write this way to avoid errors

```
$http.get("/url").then()["catch"]()["finally"]()
```

But I don't like this code style.

I've used [yuicompressor-maven-plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/) as well, but it uses YUI under the hood, so I got the same errors.

Is there a way to create minified, obfuscated JS & CSS bundles using maven?

Comment: If you are ok with npm then you can try frontend-maven-plugin - > https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin.

Comment: It starts node under the hood and gulps sources. Can it be used in production?

Comment: What do you mean in production?

Comment: Is this way stable enough for production?

Comment: Are you trying to minify files on the fly?

Comment: No, sure. Only for build stage.